# Laravel 5 - Validating Mime types

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have an uploader that works fine without rules, 
but when i create a rule i get the error:

```
LogicException in MimeTypeGuesser.php line 127:
Unable to guess the mime type as no guessers are available 
(Did you enable the php_fileinfo extension?)
```

My article request rules

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [

        'Image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg'

    ];
}
```

My form

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'blog', 'files'=> true]) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('Image', 'Upload:') !!}
    {!! Form::file('Image', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
</div>  
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You should enable the following line in your php.ini and then restart your apache

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

Enabling mean just uncomment the line in your php.ini file

i.e., From this `;extension=php_fileinfo.dll` to `extension=php_fileinfo.dll`

Comment: And what if the extension can not be enabled in certain environments?

Comment: In my PHP 7.0 MAMP (Windows) installation this line didn't even exist in `php.ini`. I added it and it worked.

Comment: is it by default enabled in hosting?

Comment: Mostly it won't be

Answer (score -2):

Mee to i had the same problem but there was no problem `extension=php_fileinfo.dll`. I change the PHP version, and the problem is fixed

Answer (score -4):

If your php.ini file don't have **extension=php_fileinfo.dll**. Don't worry, let add this line in it. Good luck!

Comment: Maybe explain why this is the solution for the question owner.