# Unable to guess the MIME type as no guessers are available (have you enable the php_fileinfo extension?) | in Symfony 5.08

Tags: php, symfony, vichuploaderbundle, symfony5, easyadmin

I got some error when i tried to upload image on easyadmin with vich_uploader.

> Unable to guess the MIME type as no guessers are available (have you enable the php_fileinfo extension?)

I have enabled php_fileinfo extension but that didn't solve this case. Also i checked my system enviroment variable and path for my php.
   I use PHP CGI 7.4.2 and symfony 5.08.

### Entity for Image (uploadable):

```
<?php
namespace App\Entity;


use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 * @ORM\Table(name="image")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"title"})
 */
class Image
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\Length(min="3")
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Length(min="10")
     */
    private $source;

    /**
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="page_image", fileNameProperty="title", size="imageSize")
     * @var File
     */
    private $imageFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     *
     * @var integer|null
     */
    private $imageSize;

    /**
     * @var bool|null
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\Length(min="10")
     */
    private $link;

    /**
     * @var Content|null
     *  @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Content", inversedBy="images")
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\Type(type="\DateTime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\Type(type="\DateTime")
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of id
     *
     * @return int
     */ 
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of id
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     *
     * @return  self
     */ 
    public function setId(?int $id)
    {
       return $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of source
     *
     * @return  string
     */ 
    public function getSource(): ?string
    {
        return $this->source;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of source
     *
     * @param  string  $source
     *
     * @return  self
     */ 
    public function setSource(string $source)
    {
        return $this->source = $source;
    }

    /**
     * @param File|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $image
     */
    public function setImageFile(?File $image=null): void
    {
        $this->imageFile = $image;
        if ($image) {

            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime('now');
        }
    }

    public function getImageFile(): ?File
    {
        return $this->imageFile;
    }

    public function setImageSize(?int $imageSize): void
    {
        $this->imageSize = $imageSize;
    }

    public function getImageSize(): ?int
    {
        return $this->imageSize;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of type
     *
     * @return  bool|null
     */ 
    public function getType(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of type
     *
     * @param  bool|null  $type
     *
     * @return  self
     */ 
    public function setType(?bool $type): void
    {
        $this->type = $type;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of link
     *
     * @return  string
     */ 
    public function getLink(): ?string
    {
        return $this->link;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of link
     *
     * @param  string  $link
     *
     * @return  self
     */
    public function setLink(string $link): void
    {
        $this->link = $link;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of title
     *
     * @return  string
     */
    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of title
     *
     * @param  string  $title
     *
     * @return  self
     */ 
    public function setTitle(string $title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of contentType
     *
     * @return  Content|null
     */
    public function getContent(): ?Content
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    /**
     * @param  Content|null  $content
     */
    public function setContent(Content $content): void
    {
        $this->content = $content;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): \DateTime
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(?\DateTime $createdAt): void
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): \DateTime
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(?\DateTime $updatedAt): void
    {
       $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }
}
```

### easy_admin.yaml

```
easy_admin:
    design:
      form_theme:
         - '@EasyAdmin/form/bootstrap_4.html.twig'
         - '@FOSCKEditor/Form/ckeditor_widget.html.twig'
    entities:
      Page:
        class: App\Entity\Page
      Content:
        class: App\Entity\Content
      Description:
        class: App\Entity\Description
        form:
          fields:
            - {property: 'description', type: 'fos_ckeditor'}
            - {property: 'descriptionENG', type: 'fos_ckeditor'}
            - 'content'
            - 'createdAt'
      Image:
        class: App\Entity\Image
        form:
          fields:
            - 'title'
            - 'type'
            - 'source'
            - 'link'
            - { property: 'imageFile', type: 'vich_image', base_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/images' }
            - 'content'
            - 'createdAt'
```

### vich_uploader.yaml

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    mappings:
        page_image:
            uri_prefix: images
            upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/images'
```

### bundles.php

```
<?php

return [
    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Twig\Extra\TwigExtraBundle\TwigExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
    Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\MakerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\EasyAdminBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    FOS\CKEditorBundle\FOSCKEditorBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Vich\UploaderBundle\VichUploaderBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];
```

### composer.json (require, require-dev)

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.10",
        "easycorp/easyadmin-bundle": "^2.3",
        "friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle": "^2.2",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.5",
        "symfony/console": "5.0.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "5.0.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.6",
        "symfony/form": "5.0.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.0.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.5",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/profiler-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/security-csrf": "5.0.*",
        "symfony/twig-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/validator": "5.0.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "5.0.*",
        "vich/uploader-bundle": "^1.13"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.16"
    },
```

Thanks.

EDIT--16.05.2020--
  I catched the issue. 
I hope it will be helpful for someone...
  What i did:
  1.Reinstalled php and composer for newest version. Made some `./bin/console c:c`
++
 2. Enabled php_extensions required also `php_fileinfo extension`
++
 3. Somehow symfony server constantly showed old php version so i made file: *.php-version* with text: *my php version assiocated to 
environment variable PATH*

Comment: Maybe it should help you : - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405960/laravel-5-validating-mime-types

Comment: Nope, unfortunately.

Comment: have you tried other file types, just as a check?

Comment: i tried jpg, png, webp